# How to assign a java script variable to xsl variable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, xslt

I have a requirement where the user enter the price in text box and i need to get the value in java script/jquery function and by using the value i need filter list data using xslt.
I have to assign the java script/jquery variable value to xsl variable and need to use it to filter the list.

Any help please i am new to XSLT.

Comment: Have you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ff806155%28v=office.14%29.aspx?

Comment: The first answer in the following question has a couple of links that you may want to look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340658/way-to-create-a-xsl-variable-using-javascript-variable-from-another-file